# Set normal orientation of origin

Tags: objects, normals

I want to change the orientation of my object to a specified direction.

Say I have an axle of a train whose *normal* orientation is set off by 90° from the *global* orientation:

[image]

The green arrow (Y-axis) points to the back of the train (along the global X-axis). But I want it to point to the sides of the train, so all I want is to rotate the orientation by 90° *without* rotating the object itself.

In other words, I want the normal and global orientation of the axle to be the identical:

[image]

Is this possible and if so, how?

Background:
The game engine to use this model will move the bogies and the axles according to their orientations. After importing this train into the game the axles rotated 90° off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the object in Object mode, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > <kbd>R</kbd> (Apply rotation). This resets the rotation to 0° around all three axes (and thus aligns the local axes with the global axes) without rotating the object.

Answer (score 1):

Get in edit mode, rotate your object in local coordinates as you wish, get back to object mode and rotate it back.

Comment: I take it you mean Edit mode. And if you do that with linked objects, it will affect all the linked objects identically.

Comment: If you're working with linked objects, the required edits will most likely need to take place in the respective source files. You suggest that going into Edit Mode for the linked objects will have unwanted effects on their relations to one another. But it's my understanding that linked objects cannot be manipulated in Edit Mode at all, except by going into their source files first.