# How to redefine x,y,z orientation of a model?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, 3d-view, workflow

I need to reset my model's x,y,z orientation.  The back of it needs to be aligned with the z axis so I can use the edge-fade method described here:

[How do you fade the edges of a model?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38094/how-do-you-fade-the-edges-of-a-model)

Right now the model's orientation seems to be at an odd angle.  Thank you for help!

EDIT: Problem solved.

[Set normal orientation of origin](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21114/set-normal-orientation-of-origin?rq=1)

This answers the question.  I am leaving my question here in case anyone else does not know to look for "normal orientation"!